# To repair or not repair?

Tags: honda, clutch, civic

I drive a 2005 Honda Civic DX, 166k miles. My clutch was having problems over the past few weeks, it would shudder the entire car when i would let it out from 1st and 2nd gear. It has since stopped and is now operating normally. Should I get it repaired or just live with it and hope it doesn't happen in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Here's an opinion

I look at the clutch as an expendable item.  It has a life span, similar to a break pad.  I've typically called them consumables.  Chains and sprockets on motorcycles, brake pads, clutches and timing belts on cars...they all have a lifespan that is relatively short in comparison to the core of the vehicle, like the frame and body.

## Answer

Replace the clutch, it's a part of the cost of owning a vehicle.  The amount of mileage on it is irrelevant.  The ability of the car to do it's job is.  If the vehicle is falling apart and this is just another component that is failing on a long list, you might want to cut your losses and get rid of it.  If it's been relatively reliable and has continued to perform it's duty of getting you from point A to point B then perhaps it's good investment to keep your reliable vehicle continuing to be a reliable vehicle.  Good luck, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

That shudder does not have to be from the clutch.  I had a broken ball joint and that caused a shudder when accelerating at low speeds.  A clutch issue should affect the car at all speeds, but it really depends on severity.